# Efficient synchronization primitives for a single-threaded async app in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have a [tokio](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio)-based single-threaded async app where using `Arc`s or other `Sync` types seems to be an overhead. Because there is no need for synchronization between threads, I am looking for something like [tokio::sync::oneshot::channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.18/tokio/sync/oneshot/fn.channel.html), `Sender` and `Receiver` of which should be `!Sync` and could be wrapped into `Rc` instead of `Arc`.

Are there any specially crafted synchronization primitives for usage in
single-threaded async apps in Rust?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the synchronization tools you're referring to. `Arc` is generally very low overhead - it's just a reference counted smart pointer, the only overhead is the atomic increment/decrement when it's cloned/dropped. Unless you're creating them in a hot loop, it shouldn't affect performance much. One-shot channels use an `Arc` internally, and so it's unlikely you could improve performance by using them instead of `Arc`.

Comment: @apetranzilla Well, a hot loop is a very likely usage case, and why to pay for atomic operations if I don't need them?

Comment: We can't offer any advice without seeing more of your use case. Do you have some sample code?

Comment: @apetranzilla Of course. I will make short samples to demonstrate the problem and update the question (this may take some time)

Comment: @kmdreko Tokio also has [LocalSet](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html) which I am using successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the various `Local` types in [futures-intrusive](https://docs.rs/futures-intrusive/0.4.0/futures_intrusive/index.html). E.g. the [LocalOneshotChannel](https://docs.rs/futures-intrusive/0.4.0/futures_intrusive/channel/type.LocalOneshotChannel.html) requires no mutex.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very interesting package written by you! I'm planning to do some testing and comparison later, and update the question to publish the results.